# How to control a camera with Delphi

Tags: delphi, api, sdk, camera

A Delphi programm should make produkt photos with a Nikon D5000AF SDX. The only commands I need are "make a photo", "get me the photo".

Which library or API can help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Heinz, to control a device you must use an SDK, which must be supplied by the manufacturer of the device.

from the [nikon](https://sdk.nikonimaging.com/apply/) site :

> ....We are offering Library Programs
>   and Command API Specifications for
>   software applications that offer
>   remote control functions for Nikon
>   digital-SLR cameras connected to a
>   computer. When these are utilized, the
>   software application can be used to
>   modify camera settings, including
>   shutter speed, aperture, and ISO
>   sensitivity, and to control camera
>   operations, including shutter release.

in [this](https://sdk.nikonimaging.com/apply/) page you can find the SDK for the Nikon cameras, including the D5000 series.

Bye.

Comment: Thanks, I have donwload the SDK. But I look for a simpler way. At the moment I am looking at "Windows Image Acquisition".

Comment: Because I don't get the WIA solution running I take a deeper look at the SDK. Is there a delphi wrapper for the SDK available?

Answer (score 9):

I would advise using the WIA (Windows Image Acquisition) API. For this you need the file "WIALib_TLB.pas" which will be created by Delphi automatically when following these steps:

1. Select "Project > Import Type Library" from the Menu
2. Select ""Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition 1.01 Type Library" from the list
3. Choose "Create Unit"
4. You will then get the unit "WIALib_TLB.pas", which by default stored in `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Imports`, which will need to be added to your library search path if it isn't already there.

Use the code from the following URL to see how you can enumerate the available devices and their properties and take a snapshot with the camera.

http://www.neunbeere.de/UseNet/WIA.html

Sorry, the comments are in German, but I think the code is easy to understand

Comment: Thanks, I have compiled your source. I get the camera properties, I can transfere photos from the camera but no picture is returned after TakePicture call (Cameras: Canon Powershout 520, Nikon D5000).

Other WIA programs have the same problems. Any ideas?

Comment: TakePicture is for Webcams, i.e. for cameras where the camera image is transferred to the computer live. TakePicture means taking a snapshot just at the very moment you call the method.

Most normal digitcal cameras that are not webcams will not allow you to take pictures while the camera is connected to the computer. You can only access the pictures that are already stored on the camera.

Comment: Looks like the asker specifically needs to be able to trigger the taking of pictures from the camera.

Comment: The code doesn't work for me, because the types in the WIA_TLB I imported don't match the types in the sample code, including the ICollection interface, which I can't find.

Comment: I guess you are using a newer version of Delphi where some of the common types like ICollection can be found in different system units.

Comment: Note: This solution is outdated. Newer versions of Windows bring different APIs to interface with devices.

Answer (score 1):

- you can use wia (windows image acquisition)
- from component menu select import component and select windows image
  acquisition and install it
- or [download](http://www.clubdelphi.com/foros/attachment.php?attachmentid=2012&d=1307029128) and add to your project
- then
- if you are use win xp
- start new project and put
- new Button named Button1
- new CheckBox named MultiPic
- and copy the cod and past in Button1

the cod:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   wia:IWia;
   WiaInf: IWiaDeviceInfo;
   wiaImg: IWiaDispatchItem;
   I:integer;
   Coll: ICollection;
begin
  wia:=CoWia.Create;
  WiaInf:= WIA.Devices.Item[0] as IWiaDeviceInfo;
  wiaImg:=WiaInf.Create;
  if MultiPic.Checked then
  begin
    coll:=wiaImg.GetItemsFromUI(UseCommonUI, MaximizeQuality);
    for I := 0 to coll.Count - 1 do
      begin
        wiaImg:=coll.Item[i]  as IWiaDispatchItem ;
        wiaImg.Transfer('C:\Source\test'+inttostr(i)+'.bmp',false);
      end;
  end
  else
  begin
    wiaImg:=wiaImg.GetItemsFromUI(SingleImage, MaximizeQuality).Item[0]  as IWiaDispatchItem ;
    wiaImg.Transfer('C:\Source\test.bmp',false);
  end;
end;
```

- i use CheckBox  to for user Determine if he want 1 picture or multi
  pictures
- you can load the Picture/s to image by **loadfromfile**