# Integrate with camera on Windows 8 Tablet

Tags: delphi

We would like to integrate the device camera into an application written in Delphi.  The device is a Dell Windows 8 tablet.  What we need is quite simple.  A button would launch the camera, passing a file name for the stored image.  Once the picture is taken, and stored in the specified file name, control would pass back to our application.  Having control go back to the Delphi app is not as important; we could write a loop to look for it and have it come to front once it is found.

What would be the simplest way to accomplish this?

Can the camera be called passing a filename parameter?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate since WIA is the answer on Win Vista, 7 and 8. A webcam is a webcam is a webcam.

Answer (score 2):

Windows comes with WIA, [Window Image Acquisition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can be used for this.

Here are some Delphi specific links:

- [Delphi: WIA to take image from digital Camera connected to USB](https://gist.github.com/stijnsanders/1724324)
- [How to control a camera with Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012630/how-to-control-a-camera-with-delphi)
- http://www.neunbeere.de/UseNet/WIA.html

Comment: Thanks I will check these out.

Comment: I have tried a bunch of these.  I seem to be in Dll Hell.  I compile on Windows7/Delphi 2007.  Is there a way to simply launch an application within a delphi app?  Like a **WinExec** or **ShellExec**?