# How do I create WIALib_TLB.dcu in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, typelib

I'm trying to compile the code snippet at https://gist.github.com/stijnsanders/1724324 using Delphi 6.

Delphi complains that WIALib_TLB.dcu can't be found.

The "Import Type Library" instructions in the snippet indeed creates and displays WIALib_TLB.pas although it's not actually in C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Imports as listed in the Project Manager, and I can't find it anywhere else, and neither can I find or create WIALib_TLB.dcu.

I'm guessing I might need to declare some kind of search path, but I'm stuck.

How do I create WIALib_TLB.dcu and get the snippet to compile?

Comment: This answer help you ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012630/how-to-control-a-camera-with-delphi

Comment: @DavidFarina Please see the self-answer.

Comment: @NineBerry Please see the self-answer.

Comment: The .dcu file doesn't exist until you've added the .pas file to your project and compiled it, at which point the .dcu will be created by the compiler.

Comment: The unit is created in C:\Users\YourName\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Imports\, and is named WIA_TLB.pas. You'll need to add this file to your uses clause yourself. See the answer to the linked post, where I edited in information about the generated file's location and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Delphi 6 generates a WIA_TLB unit, not WIALib_TLB, without definitions for IWia or IWiaDispatchItem, undoubtedly due to changes in Delphi and/or WIA between D6 and whatever Delphi version the snippet is compatible with.  (It's still not clear where the generated .pas file actually lives.)